# Codewars Python Two sum not working for some test cases

Tags: python

This Python code is not working for some test cases on code wars two sum. Here is the link to the problem:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/52c31f8e6605bcc646000082/train/python

```
def two_sum(nums, target):
    nums.sort()
    l = 0
    r = len(nums)-1
    while l < r:
        sum = nums[l] + nums[r]
        if sum == target:
            return [l, r]
        if sum > target:
            r -= 1
        if sum < target:
            l += 1
    return []
```

Any help is much appreciated! :)

Comment: Are you sure that the algorithm you're using is sound?  It's not obvious to me that this method will always converge on the valid answer where one exists.

Comment: **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: right. Maybe I'll use the hashmap method then... thanks

Comment: @itprorh66 The code is already included in the question. That link simply makes it easier to verify the answer.

Comment: But not the explanation of what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you are looking for will be:

```
def two_sum(nums, target):
    indices = {}
    for index, num in enumerate(nums):
        remainder = target - num
        if remainder in indices:
           return indices[remainder], index
        indices[num] = index
    return 0, 0
```

Right off the bat, I can also tell you that sorting nums before doing anything else is bad because the original indices can get mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

```
def two_sum(numbers, target):
    for n1 in enumerate(numbers):
        for n2 in enumerate(numbers):
            if n1[0] != n2[0]:
                if (n1[1] + n2[1]) == target:
                    return [n1[0], n2[0]]
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post